# Jquery width 100% minus pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the width on an elemrnt  to 100% minus a variable in pixels.

My `subtractWidth` variable returns a dynamic value in pixels eg: `170`

```js
$('#chartTitle').each(function(i){
  var elem = $(this);
  var parent = $(elem).parent();
  var next = $(parent).next();

  var maxWidth = '100%';
  var subtractWidth = next.width();

  elem.width(maxWidth) - subtractWidth;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="chartTitle" />
</div>
<div> ... </div>
```

Am I mising something?

Any help or advice is appreciated - thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the 170px a fixed value, or is it changing? And pls add me a snippet if u can.

Comment: @newbie it is a dynamic value

Comment: please add your HTML code too

Comment: @messerbill done

Comment: seems to be working or not? I added the snippet and made the `<input>` element self-closing to prevent an error. Now the Input field width seems to be good?

Comment: Why jQuery? Just use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Comment: what should this line `elem.width(maxWidth) - subtractWidth;` do?

Comment: @Huelfe should set width to 100% then subtract the 'subtractWidth' in pixels

Comment: Yeah I know, but you are doing nothing in this line. You don`t set the new value in this line.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First apply the 100% width and then do the calculation based on the applied width.

Your problem is that in your line `elem.width(maxWidth) - subtractWidth;` elem is setting the maxWidth which is 100% but not subtracting it after.

```js
calculate = function(){
  var total = '50%';
  var subtractWidth = $('#div1').width();

  $('#div2').width(total)
  $('#div2').width($('#div2').width() - subtractWidth);
}
```

```css
div{
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
   display: block;
   width: 0px;
  
}

#div1{
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<hr>
<div id="div2"></div>
<hr>
<button onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
```